# Opening directory function

Tags: c++, string, c++builder

This is a basic understanding concepts related question.

Working using: Embarcadero C++ Builder

What is the difference between:

```
opendir("C:\\XYZ")
```

and

```
String file = "C:\\XYZ";
opendir(file);
```

Aren't both strings?
The first one works but the sexond gives me error:
E2034 Cannot convert Unicode String to ' const char*'

In a case where I take input from the user I can only pass a string. How do i pass the whole path?

Comment: I don't know Embarcadero C++. 
But, if possible, can you try 

String file = "C:\XYZ"; opendir(file.c_str());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first one is a `const char*`, second one is a std::string. The `opendir` function accepts only `const char*` in your case and thus cannot convert `std::string` to `const char*` on its own. you can get the function to work by `opendir(file.c_str());` .

Comment: hi. for some reason it did not work when i gave it like : opendir(file.c_str()). But worked when I did: char* f = file.c_str(); opendir(f);

Comment: This is the wrong answer. `String` in this case is not `std::string`. It is actually `System::UnicodeString`, which is a C++Buider-specific string class. `System::UnicodeString` has a `c_str()`, just like `std::string` has, except that `System::UnicodeString::c_str()` returns a `wchar_t*` whereas `std::string::c_str()` returns a `const char*` instead.

Answer (score 2):

No.  A String is not a char array.  opendir needs a char array.

Answer (score 0):

`opendir()` expects an 8bit narrow `const char*` as input.  When you pass a narrow literal to `opendir()`, you are passing it a `const char[]`, which implicitly degrades to `const char*`, and all is fine.

`String` is `System::String`, which is a typedef for `System::UnicodeString`, which is Embarcadero's UTF-16 encoded string class (similar to `std::wstring`, but with different semantics).  When you pass a `String` to `opendir()`, you get a conversion error.

To pass a `String` value to `opendir()` (or any other function that expects `char*`), you need to first convert it to a `System::AnsiString`, and then use `AnsiString::c_str()` to get a `char*` from it, eg:

```
String file = "C:\\XYZ";
opendir(AnsiString(file).c_str());
```